# I can not scrape item from this website. Python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape all the clothing items in this website but I was not be able to do it. I set 'limit=3' in 'find_all' but it gives me only 1 result. How can I get all result in one request?
Please help me I am stuck with this!

[This is the e-commerce website I am trying to scrape](https://www.trendyol.com/erkek+kazak--hirka?filtreler=22%7C175)

```
def trendyol():
url = "https://www.trendyol.com/erkek+kazak--hirka?filtreler=22|175"
headers = {"User-Agent": 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/85.0.4183.83 Safari/537.36'}

page = requests.get(url, headers=headers).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "html.parser")


list= soup.find_all("div",{"class":"p-card-chldrn-cntnr"}, limit=3)
    
for div in list:
        
    link= str("https://www.trendyol.com/" + div.a.get("href"))
        
    name = div.find("span",{"class":"prdct-desc-cntnr-name hasRatings"}).text
 

print(f'link: {link}')
print(f'isim: {name}')
```

Comment: The indentation in your code is incorrect, please also be mindful of spelling and grammar. Also please describe in more detail the issue with the code you included

Comment: I am sorry, I just started to use here. I tried to edit. I hope it is more clear now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

def trendyol(url):
    headers = {"User-Agent": 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/85.0.4183.83 Safari/537.36'}
    page = requests.get(url, headers=headers).text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "html.parser")

    list= soup.find("div", {'class':'prdct-cntnr-wrppr'})
    for link in list.find_all('div',{'class': 'p-card-chldrn-cntnr'}):
        print("https://www.trendyol.com" + link.find('a', href=True)['href'])
        print(link.find('div',{'class':'image-container'}).img['alt'])
        print(link.find('span',{'class':'prdct-desc-cntnr-ttl'}).text)

url = "https://www.trendyol.com/erkek+kazak--hirka?filtreler=22%7C175&pi=3"
trendyol(url)
```

This code with print product url, title and alt text of title. Thanks.

Comment: Image is not found in soup object. Its loaded dynamically. Then it is ok. Please accept my answer. Thanks and happy to help.